# Add a Custom Footer at the end of UITableView in Xamarin.iOS

Tags: uitableview, xamarin, xamarin.ios, table-footer

I want to add a footer view to a `UITableView` that shows a `UIProgresIndicator` when the user has reached the end of the list and new data will be loaded, or a `UILabel` when there are no more data to be fetched.

I have used the code below, but nothing happens:

```
UITableViewHeaderFooterView footer = new UITableViewHeaderFooterView ();

UILabel futerlabel = new UILabel ();
futerlabel.Text = "Duke u ngarkuar";

footer.AddSubview (futerlabel);
```

Any way how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are in a `UITableViewController` try this:

```
        TableView.TableFooterView = footer;
```

**UPDATE**

After having a think about this I would suggest not using a footer but rather an extra cell at the end of your data, this will get this [effect](https://github.com/b099l3/LoadingTableExample/blob/master/Screenshots/backgroundblur.gif).

Using this method to check if you have scrolled to the last item and to update the table's data:

```
public override void WillDisplay (UITableView tableView, UITableViewCell cell, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        // if showing last row of last section, load more
        if (indexPath.Section == tableView.NumberOfSections()-1 && indexPath.Row == tableView.DataSource.RowsInSection(tableView, indexPath.Section)-1 && !FullyLoaded) {
            var growRowSource = tableView.DataSource as GrowRowTableDataSource;
            if (growRowSource != null) {
                FullyLoaded = growRowSource.LoadNextPage ();
                Task.Delay (5000);
                tableView.ReloadData ();    
            }

        }
    }
```

And then in the Delegate checking for the last item and creating a different cell like so:

```
public override UITableViewCell GetCell (UITableView tableView, Foundation.NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        if (indexPath.Row == LoadedItems.Count) {
            var loadingCell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (LoadingCellID, indexPath) as LoadFooterCell;
            loadingCell.Loading = !hasNextPage;
            return loadingCell;
        }
        var cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell (CellID, indexPath) as GrowRowTableCell;
        var item = LoadedItems [indexPath.Row];

        // Setup
        cell.Image = UIImage.FromFile(item.ImageName);
        cell.Title = item.Title;
        cell.Description = item.Description;

        return cell;
    }
    bool hasNextPage;
```

I quickly mocked an example from the GrowTable Xamarin sample code here:
https://github.com/b099l3/LoadingTableExample

Comment: Nope, I am in a UIViewController because, I have also a SearchBar and some other UIViews. I have a UITableViewSource class and a UITableViewCell custom class

Comment: I have updated my answer with a solution that might suit, let me know if you have any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You could accomplish this in several ways, I will layout a few here:

In your `TableViewSource` you can do this:

1.) Implement: `public override UIView GetViewForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)` and return your `UILabel`

2.) Implement `public override nfloat GetHeightForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)` and return a height for your `UIView`

---

If your Footer is going to be a simple UILabel, you can replace Step 1 above with this:

Implement `public override string TitleForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)` and return "Duke u ngarkuar".

You will still need to implement `public override nfloat GetHeightForFooter(UITableView tableView, nint section)` and return a height otherwise your footer wont show up.

---

Alternatively, UITableView exposes a property called `TableFooterView`that allows you to set a UIView for a footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can size this to your liking.

```
var footerView = new UIView(new RectangleF(0, 0, 375, 66));
TableView.TableFooterView = footerView;
```